# iPhone Photo Gallery Source Code

Tags: iphone, photo-gallery

I am new to iPhone development and am looking to add a picture gallery to my app that looks and acts in the same was as the iPhone photo gallery. Thumbnails leading to detail view with swipe/gesture recognisers. Please can someone help me out with the source code for this? Thanks guys!

Comment: there are lots of good examples at developer.apple.com - lots and lots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of these :

[Apple code for PhotoPicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196)

[PhotoScroller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080)

Or if you dont find anything, go and explore [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?filter=passkit#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code)